# Как сформировать и записать массив данных на Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. Имеется табличка с картинками, нужно за одну запись данных сохранить несколько адресов картинок.

Инпут выглядит следующим образом

```
<?= $form->field($image, 'url')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Как дублировать ипнут на JS я понимаю. Мне интересно как на стороне сервера должно идти сохранение в БД. Сейчас вот так

```
    $image = new Image();

    if ($image->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if($image->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $image->id_image]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'image' => $image,
        ]);
    }
```

Модель вот такая

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\admin\models;

use Yii;

/**
* This is the model class for table "image".
*
* @property integer $id_images
* @property integer $id_block
* @property string $url
* @property string $title
*
* @property Block $block
*/
class Image extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'image';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['url'], 'required'],
        ['url'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id_images' => 'Id Images',
        'url' => 'Url',
    ];
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте.
Во-первых вам нужно использовать метод **Model::loadMultiple** вместо обычного load

А во-вторых, через **save** сохранить несколько моделей не получится, в данной ситуации вам больше всего подойдет **Command::batchInsert**, который позволяет вставить в БД несколько строк за раз.
Есть небольшая проблема в том, что **batchInsert** принимает только массивы, а не **ActiveRecord**, но это легко обойти - в цикле проходитесь по всем сохраняемым моделям и получаете их атрибуты в виде массива через метод **Model::getAttributes**